# How to select behind feature which is overlapped with the same layer on QGIS 1.8.0

Tags: qgis, feature-layer, overlapping-features

My issue: I received data which was created without "Avoid intersection of new polygon". There a few overlapped feature with the same layer. I could fine overlapped feature by the spatial query. But then, I could not select behind small feature.

At present, I select target feature from attribute table and delete that feature. 
I'm hoping I could be able to select feature without attribute table.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting by attribute table is the easiest way to get those hidden features.

Another possibility is to use queries on the datasource. If Edit mode is turned off, you can right-click on the layer, select `query...` and enter a condition which will show only the hidden feature, like

```
"ref" = '14'
```

Note that the field name must be in double quotes, and the value in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

With **Identify feature** (blue rounded icon with "i" on it) tool you will get a list of features in the position (and/or very close to position) where you click.

In the **Identify Results docker** you can right click the feature and *Toggle feature selection*.

It would be great to have something similar directly with selection tool (like shift+click / alt+click) to be able to switch selection between overlapping features but it seems QGIS doesn't have such option yet.

[image]